# How to make a figcaption not move the image?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to put a `figcaption onto an image and not have it move the image from its original spot without the` figcaption`. Here is my CSS for figcaption.

Here is my code for an image with a figcaption.

```css
figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0">
  </a>
  <br>
  <figcaption>
    <div>Retouched, Untagged</div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is also a screenshot of what it looks like. The image on the left is where the image should be. The image on the left has a figcaption and it's slightly up to the left.

[image]

I am very new to coding. Anything suggestions would help. Thank you! I think there is a really simple solution to this that I'm missing.

Comment: How do you want the final output to be ?

Comment: I want the final output to be that I have multiple images with figcaptions in a row (I have it like that now) and for all of the images to be even and not uneven like in the photo. The figcaptions are beneath the images and don't interfere with the image's placement. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: `figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .75;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}`

Comment: Check my answer. Is that how you expect the output to be ?

Comment: @VXp this is really useful code! Thank you so much! On my screen the figcaption is directly on the image instead of making a new line of text. I may use this instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking  for something like this -

```css
figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

</figure>

<figure>
  <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>
  <figcaption>
    <div>Retouched, Untagged</div>
  </figcaption>

</figure>

<figure>
  <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

  <figcaption>
    <div>The image stays in same row without begin displaced</div>
  </figcaption>

</figure>
```

The above code will display all images in single row and all the captions beneath them. The images won't be misaligned  in a single row.

---

Another way of doing it would be to bring the captions over the image. This can be done as -

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-X: scroll;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 15px
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .7;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.row-separator {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

  </figure>

  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>
    <figcaption>
      <div>Retouched, Untagged</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

    <figcaption>
      <div>caption on image</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

    <figcaption>
      <div>caption on image</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>
</div>

<div class="row-separator"></div>

<div class="row">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

  </figure>

  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>
    <figcaption>
      <div>Retouched, Untagged</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

    <figcaption>
      <div>caption on image</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/CbSzPRr"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbSzPRr/Published-06-Retouced-Untagged.jpg" alt="Published-06-Retouced-Untagged" border="0"></a>

    <figcaption>
      <div>caption on image</div>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This helped me so much thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to decrease the space between the images? They usually are just a few pixels but it's a bit of space.

Comment: @XCXWorld You can use margin property for it and adjust the space between the images.

Comment: @XCXWorld I have updated my 2nd part of answer slightly. See if it is better now. .

Comment: @XCXWorld Check again,I have also included a scroll-bar for the row if you want. Also, glad to help :)